# Clear cache for specific cache name in redis spring data

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I have below method which caches `student-classes` , I want to clear only the cache name of `student-classes`

```
@Cacheable( value = "getStudentClasses",key ="(new net.student.util.CacheKeyCreator()).createKey(''+#university)",cacheManager = "cacheManager")
public List<StudentClass> getStudentClasses(String university) {
      //get studentclasses 
}
```

I have tried to clear as below, but it doesn't clear the cache with the specific name

```
@Bean(name = "cacheManager")
public CacheManager cacheManager ( RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate ) {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager( redisTemplate );
    redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(0);
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix( true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}


@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;
    
public void clearStudentClasses(){

  CacheManager cacheManager= (CacheManager) context.getBean("cacheManager");
          
  cacheManager.getCache("getStudentClasses").clear(); //exceptionLine            

 }
```

I got this exception at exception line

```
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR
> unknown command 'EVAL'; nested exception is
> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR unknown command
> 'EVAL'
```

Comment: `@Autowire org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager; and try `cacheManager.getCache("getStudentClasses").clear();`

Comment: Thank you @Thirumal for your reply , kindly find the post edited

Comment: Refer https://github.com/M-Thirumal/redi-cache. Main cache function examples are available in https://github.com/M-Thirumal/redi-cache/blob/master/src/main/java/in/thirumal/controller/CacheController.java